# password_hash returns different value every time

Tags: php, hash, passwords, php-password-hash

I'm making a login system, and I want to hash the passwords to make them more secure, but it returns a different hash every time, and can't even be verified using password_verify(), here is my code:

```
$password = password_hash($password4, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

and here is my code for verifying:

```
if(password_verify($password4, $dbpassword))
```

Comment: @PeeHaa It would take longer to crack it if it is hashed with different hashes multiple times

Comment: That assertion is incorrect @ItzBenteThePig - additional hashing makes for problems, rather than solutions. Think about what you're trying to protect. `password_hash()`, used correctly, provides random salts and long hashes that would take hundreds of years to crack.

Comment: One other note: [Don't limit passwords.](https://xkcd.com/936/)
[Passphrases are the key to higher security.](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)

Comment: @ItzBenteThePig if you have followed, to the letter, how to hash and then verify the password then there is A.) an error we don't know about or 2.) some other code which might be interfering.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

So let's take it one part at a time

> but it returns a different hash every time

That's the idea. `password_hash` is designed to generate a random salt every time. This means you have to break each hash individually instead of guessing one salt used for everything and having a huge leg up.

There's no need to `MD5` or do any other hashing. If you want to raise the security of `password_hash` you pass a higher cost (default cost is 10)

```
$password = password_hash($password4, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 15]);
```

As to verify

```
if(password_verify($password4, $dbpassword))
```

So `$password4` should be your unhashed password and `$dbpassword` should be the hash you've stored in your database