# Correct way to store passwords in PHP

Tags: php, bcrypt, password-encryption, php-7

[Fundamental difference between Hashing and Encryption algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms)

[Preferred Method of Storing Passwords In Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615704/preferred-method-of-storing-passwords-in-database)

http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

I am confused about two things. If PHP 7.0 bcrypt provides a randomized salt. How are we supposed to retrieve it for password verification?

I understand there key stretching functions like PBKDF2 but can someone explain to me why a memory intensive hashing algorithm like scrypt is preferred over something like bcrypt? Besides the brute-force attack aspect. From the logic I've read online, people recommend using scrypt with multiple iterations.

Comment: have a look upon this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108720/password-hash-returns-different-value/33109078#33109078

Comment: @Anmol thanks, not sure why I couldn't find this post.

Comment: why Scrypt is not recommended
http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/03/why-i-dont-recommend-scrypt.html

Comment: Bcrypt hashes store the salt within the hash between one off the $ delimiters. You don't need to store the salt externally. [$2y$10$TwentytwocharactersaltThirtyonecharacterspasswordhash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393803/can-someone-explain-how-bcrypt-verifies-a-hash) example of how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question about `bcrypt` and salt: *salt* is contained inside the result string as well as the *cost*, along with the hashed string. Each of three strings has constant length and thus can be retrieved easily thereafter.

For a more thorough explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833165/836646).

---

`scrypt` is a newer version of `bcrypt` that requires more RAM to operate. The reason behind the RAM requirements is that CPU cycle based encryption (I/O based) is easily brute-forced using a modern GPU, multiple cores, etc. RAM on the other side is not so easy to scale, so a combination of increased RAM + multiple operations is *theoretically* a safer way.

Read more about this in [this great answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26253/17092).