# How to fix Login function in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have this code, which runs after somebody writes his username and password, and even if i insert the correct username and password, it says "Incorrect username/password!" I have checked if I spelled something wrong, but nothing helps. Shall I also share how my register page looked / worked? Can anybody please help?

My code:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
  session_start();
}

// initializing variables
# $username = "";
# $password = "";
# $email    = "";
$errors = array(); 
   require("php_db_info.php");

// connect to the database
$connection = @mysqli_connect($servername, $username1, $password, $dbname) or die("Error: Couldn't connect to the database.");
   mysqli_select_db($connection,$dbname);

// LOGIN USER
 if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $username20 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
  $password120 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);

  if (empty($username20)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($password120)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }
if (count($errors) == 0) {
  $password_hash = password_hash($password120, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 if(password_verify($password120, $password_hash)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username20' AND password='$password_hash'";
    $results = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        # $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
          $hour = time() + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60;
        setcookie('c_username', $username20, $hour);
        setcookie('c_password', $password_hash, $hour);
        header('location: home.php');
    } else {
      array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination!");
  } 
} else {
  array_push($errors, "Unknown Error!");
}
}
}
?>

HTML: 

<?php include('server_login.php') ?>
<?php  include('show_password.js');?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Log in</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/register3.css">
  <style>
      .modal {
          padding-top: 10%;
      }  
      .error {
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 0px auto; 
  padding: 8px; 
  border: 1px solid #a94442; 
  color: #a94442; 
  background: #f2dede; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  text-align: left;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include 'loader.php';
    ?>
  <div class="modal">   
  <form method="post" action="login.php" class="modal-content">
      <div class="container1">
      <h2>Login</h2>
  <hr>
    <?php include('errors.php'); ?><br>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password">
    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn signupbtn" name="login_user">Login</button>
            </div>
            </div>
            <p>
        New Member? <a href="register.php">Register</a><br><br>
        <a href="enter_email.php">Forgot your password?</a>
    </p>
            </div>
    </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

REGISTRATION CODE:

<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

session_start();

function getValue1($r) {
    if (!isset($_GET[$r])) {
        return false;
    }
    return $_GET[$r];
}

// initializing variables
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array(); 
   require("php_db_info.php");

// connect to the database
$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username1, $password, $dbname) or die("Error: Couldn't connect to the database.");
   mysqli_select_db($connection,$dbname);

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
  $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password_1']);
  $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password_2']);
  if (getValue1('r')) {
    $r = $_POST['ref'];
}
  if (getValue('r')) {
    $referral = $_GET['ref'];
} else {
      $referral = "-";
  } 
$referral = '-';
  // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...
  // by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array
  if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required."); }
  if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required."); }
  if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required."); }
  if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
    array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match.");
  }
  $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $user_check_query);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  
  if ($user) { // if user exists
    if ($user['username'] === $username) {
      array_push($errors, "Username already exists.");
    }

    if ($user['email'] === $email) {
      array_push($errors, "Email already exists.");
    }
  }

  #$token_verify = substr(uniqid('', true), -100);
  #$sql_verify = "INSERT INTO password_reset(email, token) VALUES ('$email', '$token_verify')";
  #$results_verify = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

  // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
  if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password2 = password_hash($password_1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, coins, alltimecoins, earnedcoins, referralcoins, vouchercoins, paypal, bitcoin, referred_by, deleted, verified) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-', '-', '-', '0', '0')";
        mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
        $hour = time() + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60;
        setcookie('c_username', $username, $hour);
        setcookie('c_password', $password2, $hour);  
        header("Location: home.php");
  }
} else {
  array_push($errors, "The e-mail does not exist.");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: you are using password_verify and password_hash the wrong way

Comment: Give a try to `mysqli_num_rows($results) >= 1`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile that would have shown : `Unknown Error!`

Comment: @Cid didn't work again

Comment: Can you show us the registration code? You might have ommited `mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);` that will result a different hash. (By the way, use parameters rather than `mysqli_real_escape_string()`)

Comment: @Cid Okay, I put it in the post at the bottom

Comment: You should reduce your code to the relevant parts to make it easier to find the problem

Comment: Did you manually checked if the user was correctly inserted into the DB? (with PhpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench) and if that's the case, that the `$password_hash` (for the login part) was the same than the one in DB?

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query(...);` You might want to check `if ($result == false)` to make sure the query didn't failed.

Comment: @Cid Hm, strange. I changed the "Wrong username/password" to display the $password_hash and typed in the same password 5 times and every time it gave a different hash.

Comment: @Cid this is not how the OP should use the two functions.

Comment: Remove `$password_hash = password_hash($password120, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` and use `if(password_verify($password120, $password_stored_in_db))`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile now I got the meaning of your broad and unclear comment :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [password\_hash returns different value every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108720/password-hash-returns-different-value-every-time)

Comment: @Cid you can check detailed explanation of what I mean on the answer below

Comment: @GlobalAlliance check the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said n the comment you are using the password_hash() and password_verify() functions the wrong way.

When you have stored a password using password_hash() in the database. Do not include the password on the where clause of your select.

The hash that you hash everytime the user enters password in your form changes for every request.

take for example :

```
echo password_hash("admin",PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

The first time you run the above code it might generate :

> $2y$10$J2FhQhOYLZ2zdiHad9TNn.HeWZ6ULkh.DjP9EJPN0UtjlUD7GcxHC

When you run the same code again it will give you a different hash :

> $2y$10$raWchv0Esd5XOtB6N2R4yObgtALIp8OQ7mM2/X2ujCchPAs9RkrwC

Therefore what you need to do is select the password from the database then verify the one entered by the user against the one in the database using password_verify().

Secondly you should always use prepared statement when running your queries that have user input .

this is how your code should look :
I will only start from the part you select I will leave out other code.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {

    $username20  = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
    $password120 = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;

    if (empty($username20)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($password120)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }
    if (count($errors) == 0) {

        // $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username20' AND password='$password_hash'";
        $query = "SELECT userID,password FROM users WHERE username= ? ";

        $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($userID,$password);
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) //check if the row exists
            {
            if ($stmt->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row
                {
                //verify user password
                if (password_verify($password120, $password)) {
                    //password_verify("userenteredPassword",PasswordFromDatabase);

                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";
                    $hour                 = time() + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60;
                    setcookie('c_username', $username20, $hour);
                    setcookie('c_password', $password, $hour);
                    header('location: home.php');

                } else {

                    array_push($errors, "Password and username does not match");
                }

            }

        } else {

            array_push($errors, "Invalid user account");
        }



    } else {
        array_push($errors, "Unknown Error!");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Great, I upvote. I wouldn't have told the user that he has enter a wrong username or a wrong password, so a potential breach attempts won't tell that a username exist with a wrong password. I usually simply warn with something broader like "Wrong credentials"

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

Comment: @GlobalAlliance this is because `$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);` failed. It returns `false`.

Comment: `$query = "SELECT userID,password FROM users WHERE username= ? ";` do you have userID in your database? you need to write the exact columns as in your db @GlobalAlliance

Comment: Fixed! Thank you both for help!