# PHP password_verifiy returns true while hash is incorrect

Tags: php, password-hash

I have the following code with a userpassword contains a blow fish secret and the user password itself.

The hash is another (not the secret and the password!!) but i still got a true as result:

```
<?php
## password (secret + userpass)
$pass = 'PNvH5GFfUKktXWpydfAMXMYKayjEP3GzfJbaenmzuAHSTv7rQgW8t4ShEKpdcD5nek8eArGQyfz9XRx6ARBc897YVdetest';

## hash
$hash = '$2y$10$9VGEg7HamRVDILsFV5dvJu3l5.Psfk4g6N8.Jcn6/gMhoZIKDLAAm';

## verify
$check = password_verify($pass, $hash);

## check
if(true === $check) {
    
    var_dump($check);
    
} else {
    
    echo "false";
    
}
?>
```

I have read a lot and think it can be a problem of the length! The algo is limited to 72 chars. For more security, we have a login with a blow fish secret. While hashing, we chain blow fish + userpassword to one big password, then hash it. While login we chain blow fish and userpass again and verify. The result of this is a big password which is hashed in db.

Comment: And *why* do you have the "following code"? What practical value does it have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [password\_hash returns different value every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108720/password-hash-returns-different-value-every-time)

Comment: @shingo nope it doesn't

Comment: Why do you say the hash is incorrect? PHP evidently doesn't agree.

Comment: The code ist an example while i created a login and won't show the whole script. I have read a lot and think it can be a problem of the length! The algo is limited to 72 chars. For more security, we have a login with a blow fish secret. While hashing, we chain blow fish + userpassword to one big password, then hash it. While login we chain blow fish and userpass again and verify. The result of this is a big password which is hashed in db.

Comment: Example: Blow fish = abcdef | user pass = test | our created pass = abcdeftest < this hashed and save to db. Then after login, we do it again and verify. Should ever a hacker crack the db and stole the hashes, he has not the real password because it contains the blow fish that he not knows.

Comment: @ADyson Change the $pass value at the end and add signs - it always put out true.

Comment: Did you use `password_hash` with the `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` option? As per https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php that will indeed truncate the password to 72 characters. Demo: https://3v4l.org/Y2pTX . If you want very long passwords, I suggest using a different algorithm which doesn't have this issue.

Comment: P.S. `Should ever a hacker crack the db and stole the hashes, he has not the real password because it contains the blow fish that he not knows`...even if you didn't use the extra blowfish, the whole point of using hashes is that the hacker still doesn't know the original password. A hash is one-way, it cannot be reversed. So I don't think you actually need the extra blowfish step, simply hashing whatever the user entered is generally sufficient.

Comment: I used $cpass = password_hash($bfs.$pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); I had read about the 72 char limit. I test my script with a lower blow fish.

Comment: @ADyson Okay, thanks! I want more security and i have read this option for a long time. i know, that the hash is one way but i can change in future.

Comment: Ok yes, Bcrypt is the default algorithm currently, so using PASSWORD_DEFAULT will have the same issue. If you need to hash very long passwords, use a different algorithm which doesn't have this restriction.

Comment: I have changed my blow fish to 14 chars and limited the password field to 58 chars. So the max length is now 72 chars and it works. I added a comment at php.net for other people because there is no info about the limit.

Comment: `there is no info about the limit`...there is - it's clearly mentioned in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#refsect1-function.password-hash-parameters

Answer (score 2):

Did you use password_hash with the `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` option (or with `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`, since Bcrypt is current the default algorithm)? As per [the PHP documentation for `password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#refsect1-function.password-hash-parameters) that will indeed truncate the password to 72 characters.

Example of the issue:

```
$pass = 'PNvH5GFfUKktXWpydfAMXMYKayjEP3GzfJbaenmzuAHSTv7rQgW8t4ShEKpdcD5nek8eArGQyfz9XRx6ARBc897YVdetest';
$pass2 = 'PNvH5GFfUKktXWpydfAMXMYKayjEP3GzfJbaenmzuAHSTv7rQgW8t4ShEKpdcD5nek8eArGQ';

$hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

echo $hash.PHP_EOL;

var_dump(password_verify($pass2, $hash));
```

Live demo: https://3v4l.org/Y2pTX .

If you want very long passwords, I suggest using a different algorithm which doesn't have this issue. Either that, or don't use the extra blowfish salt (which shouldn't be necessary), or at least reduce its length.

Answer (score -2):

Please use password_hash() for generating the hash for the password then use this hash in password_verify() function.

```
<?PHP
 $pass = "secret_password";

 $hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //please use this for generating the hash



## verify
$check = password_verify($pass, $hash);

 ## check
if(true === $check) {

   var_dump($check);

 } else {

    echo "false";

 }

?>
```

Comment: I used this...$cpass = password_hash($bfs.$pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); But we still chain al blow fish secret with the userpassword and hash this. And that could be the problem since we are crossing a certain algorithm limit.